# Setting the chart cursor to change at the start of the next value

Tags: charts, amcharts

I'm having this problem with my graphs, I'm searching for the option that doesn't make the bullet jump to the second value when going a little by the middle.

I think the problem is that I'm using two dates only, But I want the value only to change just before the 07, and not when passing the middle.

2014-03-01  5
2014-03-07  8

[Left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFAkp.png)

[Right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk8Pk.png)

I need to find an option that makes the bullet change the value only when next to the new value and date. I tried a lot of settings in the creator but couldn't find anything.

Ideas?

Comment: I mailed the amCharts help & support. They told me this setting was set to true: showNextAvailable. I don't have it set to true so I will keep testing.

Comment: I solve it setting "equalSpacing" to true.